# Access to a nested array on a JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json, nested

This is the code, it use a foreach to access to department and workers .

EDIT: Will correct several paste errors

```
<?php

$json = '{
"boss": "Jeff",
"department": [{
    "office": "1111",
    "workers": "[{\"id_work\":\"123\",\"name\":\"mike\",\"mobile\":\"12345\"}]"
}]}';
$json_data = json_decode($json);
echo "Boss:".$json_data->boss;

echo "<br>";

foreach($json_data->deparment as $dep)
{

 echo "Office number:".$dep->office."<br>";

  foreach($dep->workers as $worker){
  echo "Worker ID: ".$worker->id_work."<br>";
  echo "Worker name : ".$worker->name."<br>";
  echo "Worker mobil: ".$worker->mobil."<br>";


}


}
?>
```

I cannot access to internal array when I try do a foreach() this happens :

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

How I can access to the information of the nested array

Comment: Your JSON string looks wrong, I think you need to add a `]` at the end -> `}]}`.

Comment: @Dalton just, no. There's a specific argument you can pass to `json_decode()` to force an array result and it does not look like OP requires it

Comment: I don't have some error pasting the json code here,but the json code is correct. 

But the only error this foreach($dep->workers as $worker)

Comment: Your `workers` property is a string, not an array. Looks like you've double-encoded it. Try `foreach(json_decode($dep->workers) as $worker)` or you know, fix your data format

Comment: @Landa  you can use `true` as the second parameter in `json_decode()` to convert your json to normal php array. easy to handle (for me both are easy to handle)

Comment: @AlivetoDie the format of the resulting object is definitely not the problem. If you're going to suggest OP use an array, you'll need to remind them to convert all the `->property` calls to `['property']`

Comment: @Phill holy cow you resolve my question :) THX. The main problem was the nested array

Answer (score 4):

The json data inside `$json` is wrong. The decode didn't gave errors but the array you get back is not how you want it to be, that's why you get errors after `json_decode`.

The error you got was because the worker value is in string format.
You should update that:

From: `"workers": "[{\"id_work\":\"123\",\"name\":\"mike\",\"mobile\":\"12345\"}]"`

To: `"workers": [{ "id_work": "123", "name": "mike", "mobile":"12345"}]`

---

End result:

```
$json = '{
"boss": "Jeff",
"department": [{
    "office": "1111",
    "workers": [{ "id_work": "123", "name": "mike", "mobile":"12345"}]
}]}';

$json_data = json_decode($json);
echo "Boss:".$json_data->boss;
echo "<br>";

foreach($json_data->department as $dep)
{
    echo "Office number:".$dep->office."<br>";

    foreach($dep->workers as $worker){
        echo "Worker ID: ".$worker->id_work."<br>";
        echo "Worker name : ".$worker->name."<br>";
        echo "Worker mobil: ".$worker->mobile."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx sorry for the json :/